# how to Pick items from a multi deep pallet rack

Tags: java, anylogic

I should design a warehouse with multi deep pallet. I am storing agents in multi deep pallet in a single pallet rack with a rackStore block. When I want to take the items out of the rack it tries to take the agents at the back first and I get the error saying it couldn't be picked because there are other agents in front of it.

[image: Here you see the Blocks]

I tried some code that I found here '' [Pick front item from a two deep pallet rack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176959/pick-front-item-from-a-two-deep-pallet-rack/50189629#50189629) ''

```
if(wait.size()>0 && robot.idle()>0 && rackStore.size()==0){
    Box bx=findFirst(wait,b->b.deep==0);
    if(bx!=null)
        wait.free(bx);
}
```

But it didn't work for me. I get the error ''The method findFirst(Wait, ( b) -> {}) is undefined for the type Lager.''
can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The method \*\*\*\*\*is undefined for the type\*\*\*\*\* in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136739/the-method-is-undefined-for-the-type-in-java)

Comment: The full stack trace and your own code would help narrowing down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need a wait block between your store and pick.  FindFirst is trying to find the first item in wait, but you do not have a wait block in your diagram.